# Int64.TryParse on mix concentration of integers and strings C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a personal project where I wanted to allows user to TryParse selected cell values on Datagridview (if cell values is `$4000` then TryParse button function should convert the cell value to something like `$4,000`).

Now in my case I have two buttons;

- TryParse selected cell value
- Insert `$` symbol into cell (e.g when button is pressed selected cell value should looks like `$4000`)

Now that in order to make it possible to convert a cell that contains value of `$4000` to `$4,000` I need to use a TryParse function (as far as I know), but the thing is its obviously not possible to convert `$4000` to `$4,000` because `$` is not a valid integer therefore the cell value will be 0.

Now my question is, how do I make it possible to TryParse a cell that contains value of `$nnn` to `$n,nn` (where n is positive integers)?.

TryParse the cell value on button click:

```
    private void guna2Button28_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            foreach(DataGridViewCell selected_cells in guna2DataGridView2.SelectedCells) {
                long num;
                long.TryParse(selected_cells.Value.ToString(), out num);
                string commas = num.ToString("N0");
                selected_cells.Value = commas;
            }
        } catch (Exception eq) {
            MessageBox.Show("Comma Points can only be used on integers","System",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Insert `$` symbol into cell on button click:

```
    private void guna2Button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            foreach(DataGridViewCell convert in guna2DataGridView2.SelectedCells) {
                convert.Value = "$" + convert.Value;
            }
        } catch (Exception eq) {
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred","System",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't treat grid values as data in the first place. The common way of working with data is to bind the UI element (eg grid) to a list or DataTable. Use the original data instead of the grid text

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if the first character of the string is $

```
long num;
int startPos = selected_cells.Value.ToString()[0] == '$' ? 1 : 0;
long.TryParse(selected_cells.Value.ToString().Substring(startPos), out num);
```

Comment: Thanks, I think you meant `'$' ? 1 : 0`.

Comment: Ok I encountered with this one problem where when I TryParse it the `$`  went missing. Cell values went from `$4000` to `4,000`

Comment: I've fixed it by applying `selected_cells.Value = '$' + commas` on if condition where `startPos == 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `$` with `string.Empty`. Something like...

```
string value = "$4000";
int i = Convert.ToInt32(value.Replace("$", string.Empty));
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
```